# Bash quote nesting and curly braces

Tags: bash, whitespace, filenames

As per [Change gnome-terminal title to reflect the current directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10517128/change-gnome-terminal-title-to-reflect-the-current-directory) I have tried to use:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;$(basename ${PWD})\007"'
```

... in my `~/.bashrc` to indicate the name of the current directory in the `gnome-terminal` title bar.

For the most part it works fine; but if I try to open `gnome-terminal` from a directory like:

```
/run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A001%2C008%5D/Internal shared storage/DCIM/Camera
```

... then it fails with:

```
basename: extra operand ‘storage/DCIM/Camera’
Try 'basename --help' for more information.
```

... every time the prompt is about to be shown in terminal.

Apparently the problem are the spaces in the directory name (even if the curly braces in `${PWD}` should in principle obviate the need for quotes). So, I tried escaping with quotes, and it turns out it is not trivial (apparently just a single quote escape `\"${PWD}\"` does not work) - best I could get to is:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;$(basename \\\\"${PWD}\\\\")\007"'
```

... which works without an error - but it prints an extra backslash in the gnome-terminal title; for instance, in this case, the title is: `Camera\`.

What would be the correct construction of `PROMPT_COMMAND`, so it handles directories with spaces correctly, and it prints only the directory (e.g. `Camera`) without an appended backslash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you trying to escape your double quotes?

```sh
PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;$(basename "${PWD}")\007"'
```

would be correct. We can go through the levels of nesting:

- top-layer single quotes. Inside single quotes, you do not need to escape double quotes. You would need to "escape" single quotes via `'\''` (actually, this is string concatenation, but that's not relevant here).
- second-layer double quotes. Inside double quotes, if you were trying to write literal `"`, you would need `\"`. However, you have a third layer:
- `$()` / command substitution. This layer, when executed, won't see the double quotes around it (single quotes would be a different story - you'd need `'\''`). Bash will correctly parse something like `echo "$(echo "my variable is $foo")"`.

---

Also, the curly braces in `${PWD}` have nothing to do with quotes. There is no difference between `${PWD}` and `$PWD` from any point of view. Curly braces only come into play if your variable butts up against other "word" characters:

```sh
echo PWD_$PWD_USER_$USER // expands variables "USER" and "PWD_USER_"
echo PWD_${PWD}_USER_$USER // expands variables "USER" and "PWD"
```

Comment: Thanks, @jeremysprofile - I was trying to escape those `PWD` quotes, because I thought they would interfere with the double quotes right after the `-ne`; thanks to this answer, now I know better! (also I apparently mixed up what I thought I knew about curly braces)